# MySQL Workbench - Filter Date

Tags: mysql, date, workbench

I tried researching this problem but I couldn't find anything that fits.

I have a query that pulls data the way I want, but it shows me results for the last 30 days only, the archive is about 3 years and I would like to **add a parameter** that will tell me the exact date, for example August 2019.

My query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(datetimeOrigination),
    callingPartyNumber,originalcalledPartyNumber,
    from_unixtime(datetimeDisconnect)
FROM corn.originalcdr
WHERE callingPartyNumber like '9000'
ORDER BY datetimeorigination DESC;
```

Could you please advise me on the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict, e.g., the origination datetime field to August of 2019, then add an appropriate criteria to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM corn.originalcdr
WHERE
    callingPartyNumber = '9000' AND
    FROM_UNIXTIME(datetimeOrigination) >= '2019-08-01' AND
    FROM_UNIXTIME(datetimeOrigination) < '2019-09-01'
ORDER BY
   datetimeOrigination DESC;
```

Comment: @James I can't really help you without seeing your source data.  In fact, maybe the query I gave you is correct, and you really don't have any matching data.

Comment: I can gave u remote access with AnyDesk to my server, can you help me to solve this problem ? sorry but I can't find something over the internet

Comment: Please do _not_ give your server credentials here in a comment!  Just edit your question with real sample data.

Comment: Did u have Skype or some social network ? where i can send u remote details?

Comment: Just fix your question and add sample data to make your problem _reproducible_.

Comment: I have CDR archive files on my server from 2017. for every day and hour, but MySQL Workbench shows only last month logs, i want to see logs from old CDR files,